# SQL connection in MS Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I do not know what is exactly wrong with my code, I am trying to connect this with my SQL Server, I don't know how to fix this. And in my SQL connection this is the error

> The type or namespace name 'SQLConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EndUser1
{
public partial class REGISTRATION : Form
{
    SQLConnection cn = new SQLConnection(@"Data Source=DANICA-PC;Initial        Catalog=EndUser;User ID=julio;Password=143sundea");
    SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand();
    SQLDatareader dr;

    public REGISTRATION()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void sYSTEMSETUPToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PRODUCTSETUP PRODUCTSETUPS = new PRODUCTSETUP();
        PRODUCTSETUPS.Show();
    }

    private void oRDERINGToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ORDERING ORDERINGS = new ORDERING();
        ORDERINGS.Show();
    }

    private void pAYMENTToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PAYMENT PAYMENTS = new PAYMENT();
        PAYMENTS.Show();
    }

    private void oRDERLINEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ORDERLINE ORDERLINES = new ORDERLINE();
        ORDERLINES.Show();
    }

    private void vOUCHERToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VOUCHER VOUCHERS = new VOUCHER();
        VOUCHERS.Show();

    }

    private void lISTOFREGISTEREDToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LISTREGISTERED LISTREGISTERS = new LISTREGISTERED();
        LISTREGISTERS.Show();

    }

    private void lISTOFPRODUCTSToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LISTPRODUCTS LISTPRODUCTSS = new LISTPRODUCTS();
        LISTPRODUCTSS.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(lname.Text ! =0 && fname.Text ! = 0 &&  MI.Text ! = 0  && bday.Text ! = 0 && cnumber.Text !=0 && username.Text ! =0 && pword.Text ! =0)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into info (lname,fname,MI,bday,cnumber,username,pword)values('"+lname.Text+"','"+fname.Text+"','"+MI.Text+"','"+bday.Text+"','"+cnumber.Text+"','"+username.Text+"','"+pword.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted!");
        }
    }

    private void REGISTRATION_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding `using System.Data.SqlClient;`.  Also, are you trying to use SQL or MySQL?  This is all Microsoft SQL code, but you mention my SQL (perhaps you just meant your server).

Comment: Also, **SQL INJECTION WARNING**... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx.  You may want to review how you are inserting data.

Comment: And probably best not to put your user name and password into a question when posting here.

Comment: Also: the classes you want are called `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` - with a different **spelling** than you're using! They use the `Sql` prefix - not `SQL` - and that makes a difference in C#

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a using directive to System.Data.SqlClient so the complier does not know what to do.

Add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` at the top.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx